# Are these methods to read json equivalent?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

if you have data stored as json in a column, you could query the data by

`select * from TABLE where json_column['name'] = 'Bob'`

or

`select * from TABLE where parse_json(json_column::variant):name:varchar = 'Bob'`

Are these equivalent in performance?

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not equivalent in performance, although they use a very similar path to access the "name" field.

- The first query can use metadata of JSON attributes, and you
  may see a good partition pruning.
- The second one will read all JSON data (whole partitions) and use
  parse_json on the column before fetching the field.

In short, the first query is expected to be much faster on larger datasets.

Answer (score 0):

Gokhan, is very correct, that parsing the json a second time is a complete waste of time, and given the JSON/VARIANT data is put into a auto-magic columnar form, this will kill performance.

But while we are looking at ways to write the same SQL, you can access the "name" of the json, three ways

```
with table_name(json_column) as (
    select parse_json(column1) 
    from values
    ('{"name":"not_bob","val1":10, "val2":"text tokens"}'),
    ('{"name":"Bob","val1":11, "val2":"more text"}'),
    ('{"name":"Cat","val1":"not a number", "val2":"less"}')
)
select *
    ,json_column['name'] as name_1
    ,json_column:name as name_2
    ,get(json_column, 'name') as name_3
    ,parse_json(json_column) as json_2
    ,json_2['name'] as name_2_1
    ,json_2:name as name_2_2
    ,get(json_2, 'name') as name_2_3
from table_name 
--where json_column['name'] = 'Bob'
;
```

| JSON_COLUMN | NAME_1 | NAME_2 | NAME_3 | JSON_2 | NAME_2_1 | NAME_2_2 | NAME_2_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| { "name": "not_bob", "val1": 10, "val2": "text tokens" } | "not_bob" | "not_bob" | "not_bob" | { "name": "not_bob", "val1": 10, "val2": "text tokens" } | "not_bob" | "not_bob" | "not_bob" |
| { "name": "Bob", "val1": 11, "val2": "more text" } | "Bob" | "Bob" | "Bob" | { "name": "Bob", "val1": 11, "val2": "more text" } | "Bob" | "Bob" | "Bob" |
| { "name": "Cat", "val1": "not a number", "val2": "less" } | "Cat" | "Cat" | "Cat" | { "name": "Cat", "val1": "not a number", "val2": "less" } | "Cat" | "Cat" | "Cat" |